# Do VMs skip autoboxing-unboxing in the simplest case?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, optimization, jvm

Experimenting with a simple generic interface, I found that Kotlin seems to always use Java primitives for backing non-nullable variables, and only box it in the getter. (Using IDEA's decompile feature). If you create a property that isn't based on satisfying a generic, there's no boxing. So this code:

```kotlin
interface Provider<T: Any> {
    val value: T
}

class WrappedInt(override val value: Int): Provider<Int>{
    val primitiveValue = value
}
```

compiles to this Java code (basically):

```java
public final class WrappedInt implements Provider {
   private final int value;
   private final int primitiveValue;

   public WrappedInt(int value) {
      this.value = value;
      this.primitiveValue = this.getValue();
   }

   @NotNull
   public Integer getValue() {
      return this.value;
   }

   public final int getPrimitiveValue() {
      return this.primitiveValue;
   }
}
```

What I'm wondering is if there would any value in providing the primitive copy of the property so there would be an optimized getter available when the generic interface doesn't matter. Or is the VM smart enough to skip boxing a variable that is going straight into a primitive variable or equation? For example:

```kotlin
val variable = WrappedInt(5)
val result = variable.value * 5 // Did the backing field get boxed and immediately unboxed here?
```

I'm mostly interested in Android's ART, but also JVM.

*Note that if it is true that providing a primitive property is helpful, it would be better to swap the two properties in the class definition and use a defined getter for the interface property so there is only one backing field. I only left it this way to illustrate how the backing field is a primitive regardless of the getter returning a boxed value.*

Comment: I suspect the VM does nothing related to that, it is the compiler that do boxing/unboxing (at least for Java, so can't believe it's different for Kotlin)

Comment: You're right. I didn't realize autoboxing was a compile-time event. I can see how it behaves in the bytecode.

Comment: @Tenfour04 But the bytecode is rather irrelevant for performance. The compiler adds the boxing and the JVM does Escape Analysis and possibly removes it again (it can be only done, when both boxing and unboxing land in the same method after inlining; and there's no guarantee that it happens).

Comment: Thanks, I’ll read up on escape analysis. I just ran a comparison benchmark accessing the value 2 billion times on JVM and it was equivalent using the boxed and non-boxed getters.